# View controller is not being cleared

Tags: swift

I have a view controller with a `UIScrollView`, `UIButtons`, `UILabels`, and `UIViews`. When I visit the same view controller a second time with for example a different label text value, **I can still see the objects as they were before when I visited the view controller for the first time**. This is the code I use to pop the view controller:

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: "When I visit the same view controller a second time" - do you push a new VC in the navigation controller? And after poping the VC , check the navigation stack whether the VC is still there or not.

Comment: I'll check the navigation stack now. I use a push segue to get to the aforementioned page, pop it, then use that segue again to go back and the contents of the initial visit are still on there. Hope that clarifies my situation

Comment: The view controller is not in the navigation stack when popped

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15839298/2714702

Comment: Where/How are you pulling your data?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your second view controller is not being `deinit` when popped.

Add the following code to your second view controller(only the `deinit` part) and see if it is called when you pop.

```
class MySecondViewController: UIViewController {
    deinit {
        print("Second view controller popped!")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() { ... }
}
```

If it's not called, then you have some sort of strong references between view controllers.

Comment: Where should I add this code? Within the viewDidLoad function?

Comment: @BrandonCornelio Edited the code for better understanding.

Comment: Sorry `Logger.MSG` was my personal library, use `print`

Comment: Thank you. I placed the code as instructed, ran it, and saw the "Second view controller popped!" message.

Comment: Then I guess there's something else going on.